# C# Regex - String contains at least one dot and any number of blanks

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for a Regex to test if a String only contains at least one dot "." and random number of blanks " ".

Strings that should match:

- "."
- ". ."
- " ..."
- ". .. . "
- "......"

and so on

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What did you try? This should be primitive .. too slow.

Comment: @PranavCBalan That just matches dots, what about the blanks (spaces)?

Comment: @juharr `/^[ \.]*\.[ \.]*$/`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: why all the downvotes? seems like a legitimate question. Of course @toniweser could have put some more effort into it and provide some initial regex attempts. But nevertheless it seems fine. At least some explanatory comments would help to avoid mistakes in future, also for other people like me...

Comment: @MongZhu Initially the title conflicted with the body as it only asked about matching one or more dots.

Comment: @juharr sounds reasonable. Good to know, thank you.

Comment: @juharr True. During writing the text my "requirement" changed and I forgot to change the title. Sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
^[ .]*\.[ .]*$
```

That would match exactly one dot with 0 or more dots or spaces before and after it.